# Umbraco .NET user controls - fluent NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, umbraco

Does anyone have any suggestions for plugging Fluent NHibernate (or really any ORM) into a .NET user control accessed by Umbraco?  I'm having trouble figuring out where the starting point is for creating the NHibernate session.

For example, on an ASP.NET MVC project, I can use the Applicatoin_Start and Application_BeginRequest events in the Global.asax to create a repository and inject it into my controller.  On this Umbraco project I'm working on, I'm just going to be calling a user control (ie: Search.ascx), and referencing that control directly inside of Umbraco.  Sure, I'll have the dll for it as well.  But is there a way to create an NHibernate session without having to completely set it up each time I make a request?

[This blog post](http://programmingsecrets.wordpress.com/getting-started-with-fluent-nhibernate-rtm-and-asp-net-part-i/)  looked interesting,  however it never continued on to a part 2.

Please let me know if there are any sample project/tutorials that can walk me through this.

Comment: Try asking on our.umbraco.org or search their forum, someone will have done it there and they will know umbraco better I would have thought than people on here!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I posted the question on those forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an umbraco specific question as if you have a user control it is more an ASP.Net question.

I think the recommended appraoch to to have a session per request, see:

http://ryanlanciaux.com/ryanlanciaux/post/NHibernate-Session-Per-Request.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'll look into that and see what I come up with.